# i3wm: Is there any way to toggle mouse warping behavior with a shortcut?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, mouse, i3

When I'm reading emails I want to open multiple articles in the browser before I start reading them. Therefore I'd like to disable mouse warping when I read emails but re-enable it afterwards.

I know the way to disable mouse warping in the config file is to specify `mouse_warping none`. However, I don't seem to be able to find a way to do it on the fly, via a shortcut. If I write, for example, `bindsym $mod+shift+m mouse_warping none`, I get an error

```
ERROR: Expected one of these tokens: <end>, '[', 'move', 'exec', 'exit', 'restart', 'reload', 'shmlog', 'debuglog', 'border', 'layout', 'append_layout', 'workspace', 'focus', 'kill', 'open', 'fullscreen', 'sticky', 'split', 'floating', 'mark', 'unmark', 'resize', 'rename', 'nop', 'scratchpad', 'swap', 'title_format', 'mode', 'bar'
ERROR: Your command: mouse_warping none
ERROR:               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This should really be obvious but somehow I don't seem to be able to find a way to do this.